# Trying to have user pick a list to print via integer choice

Tags: python-3.x

I have 5 empty lists pre-made, then I have the user enter 5 pcs. of info that are then appended to the list, that list then prints out the data on a single line. This repeats 4 more times with users entering in the same 5 pcs. of data. After the 5th time, the user is told they can retrieve a list by choosing 1-5. I think I've figured out how to have the lists match the choices, but I'm not sure how to have them then print out. Any help wherever it be is helpful.

Please be kind, I'm still learning.

Looking through different tutorials on linking and user input. Thinking of setting up another list to hold the previous 5 lists, but then what of the user ability to input `1` thru `5` to access each list from the overall list's index or is their a way to pull each index on its own via user choice?

```
emp_list_1 = []
emp_list_2 = []
emp_list_3 = []
emp_list_4 = []
emp_list_5 = []

# user instructions to begin creating list

print('Please enter your Employee information in the below prompts')

# user input for list 1
employeeName_1 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_1 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_1 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_1 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_1 = str(input('Salary: '))

# list 1 append
emp_list_1.append(employeeName_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeSSN_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeePhone_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeEmail_1)
emp_list_1.append(employeeSalary_1)

for count1 in range(0, len(emp_list_1)):
    print(emp_list_1[count1], end=' ')
print('')

# user input for list 2
employeeName_2 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_2 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_2 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_2 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_2 = str(input('Salary: '))

# list 2 append
emp_list_2.append(employeeName_2)
emp_list_2.append(employeeSSN_2)
emp_list_2.append(employeePhone_2)
emp_list_2.append(employeeEmail_2)
emp_list_2.append(employeeSalary_2)

for count2 in range(0, len(emp_list_1)):
    print(emp_list_2[count2], end=' ')
print('')

# user input for list 3
employeeName_3 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_3 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_3 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_3 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_3 = str(input('Salary: '))

# list 3 append
emp_list_3.append(employeeName_3)
emp_list_3.append(employeeSSN_3)
emp_list_3.append(employeePhone_3)
emp_list_3.append(employeeEmail_3)
emp_list_3.append(employeeSalary_3)

for count3 in range(0, len(emp_list_3)):
    print(emp_list_1[count3], end=' ')
print('')

# user input for list 4
employeeName_4 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_4 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_4 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_4 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_4 = str(input('Salary: '))

# list 4 append
emp_list_4.append(employeeName_4)
emp_list_4.append(employeeSSN_4)
emp_list_4.append(employeePhone_4)
emp_list_4.append(employeeEmail_4)
emp_list_4.append(employeeSalary_4)

for count4 in range(0, len(emp_list_4)):
    print(emp_list_1[count4], end=' ')
print('')

# user input for list 5
employeeName_5 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_5 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_5 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_5 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_5 = str(input("Salary$: "))

# list 5 append
emp_list_5.append(employeeName_5)
emp_list_5.append(employeeSSN_5)
emp_list_5.append(employeePhone_5)
emp_list_5.append(employeeEmail_5)
emp_list_5.append(employeeSalary_5)

for count5 in range(0, len(emp_list_5)):
    print(emp_list_1[count5], end=' ')
print('')


#trying to create new list with other lists listed inside it, not sure it can work tho?!

all_e_lists = [ ]

e_l_1 = emp_list_1
e_l_2 = emp_list_2
e_l_3 = emp_list_3
e_l_4 = emp_list_4
e_l_5 = emp_list_5



# Next user request info
print("You can pull an individual's list by entering 1 - 5")

query_emp_list = str(input('Choose 1 - 5: '))
if query_emp_list in emp_list_1 :
    print()
```

Hoping that if user chooses `1`, list one prints out like this:

`Mike Smith 123121234 (111)222-3333 Mike@gmail.com $6000`

If they choose `4`, they get this:

`Galaxy Note 110101010 (110)222-3310 Galaxy@samsung.net $1100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shorter version of your code

```py
print('Please enter your Employee information in the below prompts')

def enterEmployee():
  name = str(input('Name: '))
  SSN = str(input('SSN: '))
  phone = str(input('Phone: '))
  email = str(input('Email: '))
  salary = str(input('Salary: '))
  employee = [name, SSN, phone, email, salary]
  print(' '.join(employee))
  return employee

all_e_lists = [ ]
for _ in range(5):
  all_e_lists.append(enterEmployee())

# Next user request info
print("You can pull an individual's list by entering 1 - 5")

query_emp_list = int(input('Choose 1 - 5: ')) - 1
if 0 <= query_emp_list < len(all_e_lists):
  print(' '.join(all_e_lists[query_emp_list]))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help  on shortening this down. I'm still very much new and some of the concepts that are being applied are above my understanding for the moment, but I will take them into consideration going forward as I am no doubt sure they will come in handy down the road. I incorporated the last section with the if statement to allow the conversion of the indexed lists from 0 to 4, to 1 to 5 as that was still something I was still misunderstanding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

To add something to a list after it was made, use the `.append()` function.

```
# Define the list
all_e_lists = [ ]
# Add the other lists
all_e_lists.append(emp_list_1)
all_e_lists.append(emp_list_2)
all_e_lists.append(emp_list_3)
all_e_lists.append(emp_list_4)
all_e_lists.append(emp_list_5)
```

You could also just add the lists when you define the list.

```
# Define the list with all other lists
all_e_lists = [ emp_list_1, emp_list_2, emp_list_3, emp_list_4, emp_list_5 ]
```

When you want the user to input which list to use, you can just access the list by index

```
# Get which list the user wants
query_emp_list = int(input("Choose 1-5: "))
# Iterate through each value in the selected list
for value in all_e_lists[query_emp_list]:
    # Print the value with a space at the end
    print(value, end = ' ')
```